# Attaching Core Data Entities using Relationships

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have two Core Data entities, `Car` and `Services`. I want a car to have multiple services so I made the car relationship to `Services` a `to-many` Type.

If I look at my database, I have a `Car` table with its attributes and a `Services` table with its attributes, both saving to their respective tables.

The problem is that I can not figure out to get a service to attach to a car. When looking at the `Services` table there is a column for Car. I know that there are some methods in the `Car+CoreDataProperties.swift` file such as `addToServices(_ value: Service)` & `addToServices(_ value: NSSet)` but when I try to call one of those methods and pass in my service data I get this error:

```
CoreData: error: +[Services entity] Failed to find a unique match for an NSEntityDescription to a managed object subclass
```

Here's the code that invokes that error:

```
func saveToCoreData() {
    let car = Car(context: self.moc)
    let service = Services(context: self.moc)
    service.date = date
    service.serviceType = self.serviceType
    service.serviceCost = self.serviceCost
    service.serviceComplete = self.servicecComplete

    let serviceData: NSSet = [service.date, service.serviceType, service.serviceCost, service.serviceComplete]
    car.addToServices(serviceData)
    try? self.moc.save()
}
```

To possibly make all of this more difficult, the data is being entered via a form I made using SwiftUI.

Comment: What if you call `car.addToServices(service)`?

Comment: So I replaced `car.addToServices(serviceData)` with `car.addToServices(service)`, now it won't save a service to the `Services` table at all. I have the same method as I originally posted above but with `car.addToServices(service)`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check `self.moc.save()`. If it failed there would be no changes visible in the database.
2. `addToServices(_ value: Service)` and `addToServices(_ value: NSSet)` are overloaded methods. The first one adds a (single) `Service` object to a `Car` object and the second adds a set of `Service` objects to a `Car` object.
3. In order to set a car's service(s) you have alternative ways to do that:

   - **A)** (as mentioned by @nighttalker) `car.addToServices(service)`
   - **B)** `car.addToServices([service])`
   - **C)** A) and B) add new service(s), but if you want to *replace* the currently existing services, or set service(s) of a car for the first time, use: `car.services = [service]`.

About the error: `car.addToServices(serviceData)` failed because `serviceData` is neither of type `Set<Service>` nor `Service`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. At what point does the data get written to the database then, at the time of the app closing? After adding a service and closing the app I get this error `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 "model is a required value." UserInfo={NSValidationErrorObject=<Car: 0x6000030e5db0>` . I have model set as a non-optional attribute in the xcdatamodeld and in the class extension.

Comment: What i said about database update was wrong (sorry). I've updated it. Changes are visible after a _successful_ `moc.save()`.  When `car.model` is non optional but not set `moc.save()` will fail and there will be no inserts or updates.